# How to remove the dropdown icon on a WPF ToolBarTray?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolbar

How can I get rid of the grey dropdown area to the right of the text in the toolbar item below?

[image]

Here is the code which produces it:

```
ToolBar tb = new ToolBar();
tb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "test";
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
tb.Items.Add(button);
value.ToolBars.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property in the ToolBar class which allows you to do this. But you can always override ToolBar's style. Get default style for you theme. Usually that thumb part is called "OverflowGrid". Just remove it or make it hidden.

Hope that answers your question. But I'm wondering why do you want to remove it? Are you sure you need toolbar control there at all? Maybe raw ItemsControl with proper colors will work for you?

Comment: No example was given; the answer is lazy, incomplete, and not suitable for this site. Thus, my downvote.

Answer (score 5):

```
<ToolBar Height="120">
        <ToolBar.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToolBar">
                <!-- Not Dropdown Button -->
                <Setter Property="ToolBarTray.IsLocked" Value="True"/>
                <!-- Not Overflow Button -->
                <Setter Property="OverflowMode" Value="Never"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                            <ToolBarPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToolBar.Style>
        <!-- Content -->
        ........
        <!-- End Content -->
</ToolBar>
```